# rsplit method for re.compile

Tags: python, regex, python-re

`re.Pattern` objects have a `split` method:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.compile('b').split('abcadrewbafdsba', maxsplit=2)
['a', 'cadrew', 'afdsba']
```

Is there a way to do an `rsplit`, however?

Desired output would be something like:

```
>>> re.compile('b').rsplit('abcadrewbafdsba', maxsplit=2)
['abcadrew', 'afds', 'a']
```

I'm aware that I don't need regex to split on a single character, this is just a simplified example

Comment: this is not only for `re.compile`, `re` also doesn't have a `rsplit` method

Comment: You can create a regex which anchors to the end of the string to force it to split relative to it. For example, `re.split(r'b(?=[^b]*$)', string)`; or for your example, `re.split(r'b(?=[^b]*(?:b[^b]*)?$)', 'abcadrewbafdsba')`